# individual ngClass in a ngFor loop, angular 6

Tags: angular

I am trying to change the class of a specific position in my *ngFor, for example:

HTML

```
<table>
 <tr *ngFor="let article of articles; let i = index">
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="articles[i].name" [ngClass]="{'is-valid': wrongArticle == false }" (change)="checkArticle(i)" >
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

TS

```
articles = [{name: ""}, {name: ""}, {name: ""}]
wrongArticle: boolean = true;

 checkArticle(i){
  if(this.articles[i].name != ""){
  this.wrongArticle = false;
  }
 }
```

So... my problem is... when i type something in any input... the class 'is-valid' is applied in every input... how can i apply 'is-valid' just in the correct input?

Comment: you are calling a checkArticle() from the html but u are not passing the paramter, why ? because in ts file that function is expecting an arguement

Comment: upss i missed that, edited

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of defining 'wrongArticle' globally. try to use 'wrongArticle' property in the article row. I have created a working sample application [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2ftrry?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Here is the ts code

```js
 articles = [{name: ""}, {name: ""}, {name: ""}]
wrongArticle: boolean = true;

 checkArticle(article:any){
  if(article.name != ""){
  article.wrongArticle = false;
  }
 }
```

here is the html code

```js
<table>
 <tr *ngFor="let article of articles; let i = index">
  <td>
    <input type="text" name="name" [(ngModel)]="articles[i].name" [ngClass]="{'is-valid': article.wrongArticle == false }" (change)="checkArticle(article)" >
  </td>
 </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: oh great, that is what i needed, i didnt think about add this value as a property, thanks!!