# change class based on radio button checked angular using ngfor, ngClass, ngChange

Tags: angular, ngfor, ng-class

```
<div>
<label *ngFor="let article of articles; let i = index" [ngClass]="{'is-valid': isChecked}">
<input type="radio" name="name" (change)="isChecked = true">
  input{{i}}
</label>
```

Here the 'isChecked' class is applied for all labels based upon input, but the class is not removed even I select another option.

I tried this way, but it doesn't remove the class if input is unchecked.
[individual ngClass in a ngFor loop, angular 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53076168/individual-ngclass-in-a-ngfor-loop-angular-6/62842543?noredirect=1#comment111130436_62842543)

I created a slackblitz example
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngclass-ngfor-change

Thanks in advance

Comment: Stackblatz code is different then ur question code.
check if its what u need ?
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-b2vxfs?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts
I have froked ur stackblitz

Comment: @hanan, I can't find the slackblitz demo link you sent. Here is my updated link.
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngclass-ngfor-change

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this solution works.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngclass-ngfor-change-m2d1hy

```
<div>
<label *ngFor="let article of articles; let i = index" [ngClass]="[article.isChecked ? 'is-valid' : 'is-notvalid']">
<input type="radio" name="name"  (change)="checked(i)" >
  input{{i}}
</label>
```

```
export class AppComponent  {
name = 'Angular';
articles = []
isChecked: boolean = false;
constructor(){
this.articles.push({ "isChecked" : false});
this.articles.push({ "isChecked" : false});
this.articles.push({ "isChecked" : false});
}
test= "";
checked(i){  
this.articles.forEach(x=> x.isChecked = false);
this.articles[i]['isChecked'] = !this.articles[i]['isChecked'];
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```html
<div>
<label *ngFor="let article of articles; let i = index" [ngClass]="{'is-valid': !!article.isChecked}">
<input type="radio" name="name" (click)="article.isChecked = !article.isChecked">
  input{{i}}
</label>
```

Comment: It doesn't work. It adds the class but doesn't remove it. All inputs are blue color.

Comment: I changed ngclass like this, still doesn't work. 
[ngClass]="[isChecked ? 'is-valid': 'is-notvalid']"

Comment: oh a mistake one min

Comment: @yash- this doesn't work either. Is it possible to share a slackblitz example.